# In Trello, how do I replace one label with another?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

When I brought cards from one Trello board into another, their labels were added to the second board's list of labels, creating duplicate labels which have the same name and color. This makes the list of labels very long. Is there a way to remove the duplicate label and just apply the remaining one to the cards that had it, without having to do it to each one individually? I found the helpful site https://batch.cardsync.xyz/ but it doesn't seem to have that function.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the Bulk Actions power-up which can do this I think.

To do this manually I would

1. Filter the board to just those cards (press 'F' then select the label you want to change)
2. Hover over each card and press the number key associated with the label you want to remove, then the number for the label you want to add. Use some trial and error to find the correct numbers!

However, if the label colours and names are exactly the same Trello shouldn't duplicate them. You could double-check the Label names are the same, remove the imported cards and re-add them?